# List Matching in Python using nested for loops

Tags: python

I have three lists, (1) treatments (2) medicine name and (3) medicine code symbol. I am trying to identify the respective medicine code symbol for each of 14,700 treatments. My current approach is to identify if any name in (2) is "in" (1), and then return the corresponding (3). However, I am returned an abitrary list (correct length) of medicine code symbols corresponding to the 14,700 treatments. Code for the method I've written is below:

```
codes = pandas.read_csv('Codes.csv', dtype=str)
codes_list = _codes.values.tolist()

names = pandas.read_csv('Names.csv', dtype=str)
names_list = names.values.tolist()

treatments = pandas.read_csv('Treatments.csv', dtype=str)
treatments_list = treatments.values.tolist()   

matched_codes_list = range(len(treatments_list))
for i in range(len(treatments_list)):
    for j in range(len(names_list)):
        if names_list[j] in treatments_list[i]:
            matched_codes_list[i]=codes_list_text[j]
print matched_codes_list
```

Any suggestions for where I am going wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `codes_list_text`?  I don't see it defined.

Comment: is each `treatment` a list of medicine names?

Comment: @scott hunter codes_list_text is meant to say codes_list

Comment: @gariepy yes, each treatment is a list of medicine names, along with occasionally additional words that describe the treatment in further detail

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you are expecting.  You should replace the xxx_list code with examples instead, since you don't seem to have any problems with the csv reading.

Let's suppose you did that, and your result looks like this.

```
codes_list = ['shark', 'panda', 'horse']
names_list = ['fin', 'paw', 'hoof']
assert len(codes_list) == len(names_list)
treatments_list = ['tape up fin', 'reverse paw', 'stand on one hoof', 'pawn affinity maneuver', 'alert wing patrol']
```

it sounds like you are trying to determine the 'code' for each 'treatment', assuming that the number of codes and names are the same (and indicate some mapping).  You plan to use the presence of the name to determine the code.

we can zip together the name and codes list to avoid using indexes there, and we can use iteration over the treatment list instead of indexes for pythonic readability

```
matched_codes_list = []
for treatment in treatment:
    matched_codes = []
    for name, code in zip(names_list, codes_list):
        if name in treatment:
            matched_codes.append(code)
    matched_codes_list.append(matched_codes)
```

this would give something like

```
assert matched_codes_list == [
  ['shark'],                    # 'tape up fin'
  ['panda'],                    # 'reverse paw'
  ['horse'],                    # 'stand on one hoof'
  ['shark', 'panda', 'horse'],  # 'pawn affinity maneuver'
  [],                           # 'alert wing patrol'
]
```

note that the method used to do this is quite slow (and probably will give false positives, see 4th entry).  You will traverse the text of all treatment descriptions once for each name/code pair.

You can use a dictionary like 'lookup = {name: code for name, code in zip(names_list, codes_list)}, or itertools.izip for minor gains.  Otherwise something more clever might be needed, perhaps splitting treatments into a set containing words, or mapping words into multiple codes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a ton! By slow, how long exactly do you think this should take? It's been almost an hour so far

Comment: You can add something pretty easily to print out progress, perhaps a "." to stderr for every 2% complete.  The current version has to traverse the full text of all the treatments once for each name, if there are lots of names or long treatments, this can be easily be slow, can't give an estimate without more info, sorry.